# How to check if array contains an item in JSON column using Sqlite?

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, case, where-clause

I'm using sqlite to store JSON data that I have no control over. I have a **logs** table that looks like this.

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| s8i13s85e8f34zm8vikkcv5n | {"key":["a","b"]} |
| m2abxfn2n9pkyc9kjmko5462 | {"key": "sometext"} |

Then I use the following query to get the rows where `value.key` contains `a`:

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM json_each(json_extract(logs.value,'$.key')) WHERE json_each.value = 'a')
```

The query works fine if key is an array or if it doesn't exist. But it fails if is a string (like the second row of the table)

The error I get is:

`SQL error or missing database (malformed JSON)`

And it is because `json_each` throws if the parameter is an string.

Because of the requirements I can't control the user data or the queries.

Ideally I would like to figure out a query that either doesn't fail or that detects that the value is a string instead of an array and uses `LIKE` to see if the string contains `'a'`.

Any help would be appreciated. Happy holidays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause which checks if the value is an array or not:

```
SELECT * 
FROM logs 
WHERE CASE
  WHEN value LIKE '{"key":[%]}' THEN
    EXISTS (
     SELECT * 
     FROM json_each(json_extract(logs.value,'$.key')) 
     WHERE json_each.value = 'a'
    )
  ELSE json_extract(value,'$.key') = 'a'
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WH2d2Gyz).

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!

I did a couple of changes to better support my use case:

1 - Use json_extract on the CASE to check specifically for the key, otherwise it would go to the ELSE expression if the value column had any other keys.

2 - Use the LIKE operator instead of = on the ELSE expression, that way I can check for strings or arrays that contain `x` with a single query.